# How to write an if statement inside of an API call to resemble a loading state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, components

I take a value from user input and put it into an API call as a `argument` showing results related to the user's input. When that API data is loading. For simplicity, I want to log to the console 'Loading' and when the data is loaded, `console.log` the data. I don't know how to set up an if statement in between my `axios` call.

Also, am I using `state` properly? Should I define the `query` value and `isLoading` in the `constructor`?

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      movieList: [],
    }
  }


  // propped value from user input which goes inside the API call as a parameter
  handleSearch = (value) => {

    this.setState({
      query: value,
      isLoading: true
    })

    //if isLoading === true --> console.log('Loading');
    axios({
      url: `apicall${value}2`,
      method: 'GET',
      responseType: 'JSON',
      // isLoading === false --> console.log('movieList');
    }).then((response => {
      let movieList = response;
      
      this.setState({
        movieList,
        isLoading: false,
        query: ''
      })

    }))
  }
```

Comment: Why you want to add if statements, you can simply add logs as 'loading' before the axios call and 'movieList' in then() function .

Comment: I guess you have not defined other variables in state inside constructor

Answer (score 0):

In your code you don't have `query` and `isLoading` in the state. I updated them in below code.

To `console.log` before and after making an API call in your code, `setState`s callback function can be used.

And I refactored code to look clean.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      movieList: [],
      query: "",
      isLoading: false
    };
  }

  movieListSearchInitiated = value => {
    this.setState(
      {
        query: value,
        isLoading: true
      },
      () => {
        // Use setStates callback function to log

        console.log("Loading");
      }
    );
  };

  movieListSearchSuccess = movieList => {
    this.setState(
      {
        movieList,
        isLoading: false,
        query: ""
      },
      () => {
        // Use setStates callback function to log

        console.log(this.state.movieList);
      }
    );
  };

  movieListApiCall = value => {
    return axios({
      url: `apicall${value}2`,
      method: "GET",
      responseType: "JSON"
    });
  };

  handleSearch = value => {
    this.movieListSearchInitiated(value);
    this.movieListApiCall(value).then(movieList => {
      this.movieListSearchSuccess(movieList);
    });
  };
}
```

I hope you are error handling the API request.